# removing "table.include.list" does not force Debezium to create topics for the rest of tables in database

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I created Debezium connector, that works like a charm:

```json
{
    "name": "debezium_title",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "xxx.xxx.xxx",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "kafkaconnect",
        "database.password": "***",
        "database.server.name": "mysql_debezium",
        "heartbeat.interval​.ms": 5000,
        "snapshot.mode": "when_needed",
        "snapshot.new.tables": "parallel",
        "database.include.list": "database",
        "table.include.list": "database.table1,database.table2",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "mysql_debezium_history",
        "database.history​.kafka.recovery​.poll.interval.ms": 5000,
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "xxx.xxx.xxx:9092",
        "include.schema.changes": "false",
        "transforms": "extractInt",
        "transforms.extractInt.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
        "transforms.extractInt.field": "id"
    }
}
```

Right now, I want to delete this connector and create new one without whitelist of tables - to ingest the whole database:

```json
{
    "name": "debezium_title_new",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "xxx.xxx.xxx",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "kafkaconnect",
        "database.password": "***",
        "database.server.name": "mysql_debezium_new",
        "heartbeat.interval​.ms": 5000,
        "snapshot.mode": "initial",
        "database.include.list": "database",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "debezium_mysql_history_new",
        "database.history​.kafka.recovery​.poll.interval.ms": 5000,
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "xxx.xxx.xxx:9092"
    }
}
```

with new: connector name, database server name and database history kafka topic name.

What is strange, it created only topics, for tables that I set in `"table.include.list"` for the first connector!

```sh
kafka-topics --list --zookeeper xxx.xxx:2181

mysql_debezium_new.table1
mysql_debezium_new.table2
```

And after a while error occured:
`Encountered change event for table database.table3 whose schema isn't known to this connector` (table3 is an example of table from database that wasn't on whitelist in the first connector)

Where is the rest of tables from my database? :) How can I force Debezium to move all of the tables from mysql, when I already have the connector with whitelist of tables (to delete first connector and create new one without whitelist does not help).

I also tried just adding new tables to whitelist and it does not work either - it doesn't create new topic and doesn't load the whole table - it waits for the first new record in table, and then error occurs: Schema is not know for this table.

How is that? Does Debezium take a database snapshot for the first connector, then save it somewhere and keep it? How can I reset it?

Debezium version: 1.5

Comment: Apart from using the first config did you make any other changes? I am also trying to set up this on local and have a motor.books table on local mysql.         "database.server.name": "mysql_debezium_new",         "database.history.kafka.topic": "debezium_mysql_history_new", Can these values for server.name / kakfa.topic be anything or has to follow some convention?

Answer (score 0):

That parameter is optional, if you want it to get all non-system tables omit that parameter altogether.

> From the Documentation:
> *An optional comma-separated list of regular expressions that match fully-qualified table identifiers for tables that you want Debezium to capture; any table that is not included in table.include.list is excluded from capture. Each identifier is of the form schemaName.tableName. By default, the connector captures all non-system tables for the designated schemas. Must not be used with table.exclude.list.*

Link to the aforementioned Debezium documentation: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/sqlserver.html

Answer (score 0):

@Gignak, here are a few of my suggestions:

To delete a connector use:

```
curl -i -X DELETE <host>:<port>/connectors/debezium_title
```

To create a new connector use:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" <host>:<port>/connectors/ --data "<your json path>"
```

I also suggest to at least specify the scheuma when you require all the tables of that schema, so you can include this parameter into your json:

```
"schema.include.list": "<your_schema>"
```

And remember, at the moment (2023/05) old topics will not be deleted when you stop or delete the connector and therefore you should do it differntly.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to delete the kafka topic and re-run the application. It will work.